# How to join tables using setDT in R

Tags: r, merge, data.table

```
library(data.table)
table1 <- data.frame(id1 = c(1324, 7822, 2324, 29, 9999, 1010),
                     class = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1),
                     type = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "D"),
                     number = c(1, 2.5, 98, 100, 80, 50))
table2 <- data.frame(id2 = c(1992, 1987, 1998, 1998, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2010, 2012),
                     class = c(3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1),
                     type = c("B", "C", "D", "A", "D", "D", "C", "B", "A"),
                     min_number = c(0, 0, 34, 0, 20, 45, 5, 23, 1),
                     max_number = c(18, 18, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 9, 10))
```

I have 2 tables that look like this:

```
> table1
   id1 class type number
1 1324     1    A    1.0
2 7822     1    A    2.5
3 2324     1    A   98.0
4   29     2    B  100.0
5 9999     2    C   80.0
6 1010     1    D   50.0

> table2
   id2 class type min_number max_number
1 1992     3    B          0         18
2 1987     3    C          0         18
3 1998     1    D         34         50
4 1998     1    A          0        100
5 2000     3    D         20        100
6 2000     1    D         45        100
7 2000     2    C          5        100
8 2010     5    B         23          9
9 2012     1    A          1         10
```

I would like to merge the two tables based on the same `class` and `type`. In particular, I would like to extract the `id2`s from `table2` and store them in `tab1_tab2`.

```
tab1_tab2 <- setDT(table1)[setDT(table2), on = c("class", "type"), 
           id2 := id2]

> tab1_tab2
    id1 class type number  id2
1: 1324     1    A    1.0 2012
2: 7822     1    A    2.5 2012
3: 2324     1    A   98.0 2012
4:   29     2    B  100.0   NA
5: 9999     2    C   80.0 2000
6: 1010     1    D   50.0 2000
```

Notice that for `class=1` and `type=A`, there are actually 2 `id2`s: `1998` and `2012`. However, `tab1_tab2` only stored `2012`.

I would like the final output to store all possible `id2`s, each separated by `;`. It should look something like this:

```
> final_tab1_tab2
    id1 class type number       id2
1: 1324     1    A    1.0 1998;2012
2: 7822     1    A    2.5 1998;2012
3: 2324     1    A   98.0 1998;2012
4:   29     2    B  100.0        NA
5: 9999     2    C   80.0      2000
6: 1010     1    D   50.0 1998;2000
```

This is a toy example, so the tables are small. In reality, my tables have thousands of rows, so I want to avoid using a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
table1[, id2 := table2[, .(id2 = paste(id2, collapse = ";")), by = .(class, type)][table1, on = .(class, type)]$id2]
#               <-- 1) aggreagtion                                             -->
#               <-- 2) left-join                                                                            -->
#                                                                                                              3) extract
#        <-- 4) assignment by reference                                                                          -->
```

Result

```
table1
#    id1 class type number       id2
#1: 1324     1    A    1.0 1998;2012
#2: 7822     1    A    2.5 1998;2012
#3: 2324     1    A   98.0 1998;2012
#4:   29     2    B  100.0      <NA>
#5: 9999     2    C   80.0      2000
#6: 1010     1    D   50.0 1998;2000
```

---

Above we

1. aggregate `table2`, then
2. perform a left-join,
3. extract new `id2` from the result of 2.
4. and assign `id2` by reference to `table1`

**data**

```
library(data.table)
table1 <- data.table(id1 = c(1324, 7822, 2324, 29, 9999, 1010),
                     class = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1),
                     type = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "D"),
                     number = c(1, 2.5, 98, 100, 80, 50))
table2 <- data.table(id2 = c(1992, 1987, 1998, 1998, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2010, 2012),
                     class = c(3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1),
                     type = c("B", "C", "D", "A", "D", "D", "C", "B", "A"),
                     min_number = c(0, 0, 34, 0, 20, 45, 5, 23, 1),
                     max_number = c(18, 18, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 9, 10))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use a semi-colon for the delimiter instead of a comma?

Comment: Adrian, you can replace `toString(id2)` with `paste(id2, collapse=";")`

Comment: @Adrian Sorry I missed that detail. I updated the answer and added some explanation too. Thanks r2evans!

Comment: For my own understanding, could you explain what `:=` means? And also what does `.` mean in front of `.(class, type)`? I've never seen these while working with a `data.frame`.

Comment: Hey Adrian, this is `data.table` syntax. You can read about it in the vignette [Reference semantics](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html)

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
setDT(table2)[setDT(table1),.(class,type,number,id1,id2=x.id2),on=("class", "type")][
              ,.(id2=.(id2)),by=.(class,type,id1,number)]

# class   type   id1 number       id2
# <num> <char> <num>  <num>    <list>
#   1:     1      A  1324    1.0 1998,2012
# 2:     1      A  7822    2.5 1998,2012
# 3:     1      A  2324   98.0 1998,2012
# 4:     2      B    29  100.0        NA
# 5:     2      C  9999   80.0      2000
# 6:     1      D  1010   50.0 1998,2000
```